# Flows: prevent rerun of custom validation rules

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule

Salesforce are no longer allowing workflow rules or field updates to be created, and are informing developers to use flows.  I have come across one significant difference which is causing us issues. This article here - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm - explicitly states:

**If there are workflow field updates:
Updates the record again.
Runs system validations again. Custom validation rules, flows, duplicate rules, processes, and escalation rules aren’t run again.
Executes before update triggers and after update triggers, regardless of the record operation (insert or update), one more time (and only one more time)**

Specifically when dealing with custom validation rules, this does not appear to apply to flows which update a record.  I am observing that custom validation rules are run again. So my question is: is there a config option in the flow to prevent rerun of custom validation rules?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at this blog post and video from the admin.salesforce.com site:
https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2022/how-i-solved-it-bypass-validation-rules-in-flows

It appears to answer this problem.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It would be better if you summarized the important points from the blog/video. Salesforce doesn't exactly have the best track record when it comes to longevity of links.

Comment: Updated with screenshots of the article...